# storing database connection credentials

Tags: database, connection, credentials

i am going to start working on a multi-user application and wondering about following: 
what is best practice to store the database connection credentials for my application? do i have to write it into the configuration file? is storing it remotely an option? how to update the credentials when needed within all installed applications?

the whole application would run in a private network, multiple installations and one database.

in college we learned alot about databases and coding but sadly very little about connecting them with each other in practice. maybe you got some best-practice tips.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to store locally in a configuration file. Most technologies and frameworks have convention for this, such as the web.config for .NET.